# lateinit property has not been initialized with dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I am new to Android and I am trying to create an app with Dagger2 and MVVM pattern and kotlin, but I cannot make it run.

My application class code.

```
class PruebaDaggerApp: Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

@Inject
lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(this)

}


override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector

override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> = fragmentInjector
```

}

My AppComponent.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

     fun inject(app: Application)

}
```

ActivityModule code

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun contributesMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

FragmentsModule code

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentModule {

   @ContributesAndroidInjector
   abstract fun contributesCardFrament(): CardFragment

}
```

AppModule code

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule(val app: PruebaDaggerApp) {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApplicationContext(): Context = app.applicationContext

 }
```

ViewModelModule

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(CardViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindCardViewModel(viewModel: CardViewModel): ViewModel


    }
```

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property activityInjector has not been initialized
>           at org.ottochamo.pruebadagger.PruebaDaggerApp.activityInjector(PruebaDaggerApp.kt:28)
>           at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:56)
>           at dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.onCreate(DaggerAppCompatActivity.java:43)
>           at org.ottochamo.pruebadagger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2828)

I've been following a lot of articles yet I cannot make it work. I would appreciate your help a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
```

but you do not provide appContext for AppModule which is required in constructor:

```
class AppModule(val app: PruebaDaggerApp) {}
```

So you should create your AppComponent like:

```
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build().inject(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I requested injection `Application` instead of my class `PruebaDaggerApp` and that fix it :)